Propagating measurement uncertainty with posterior predictions as data in another model
I'm working on a modeling approach that incorporated estimates of measurement uncertainty trying to use brms in R. I'm working from the example in chapter 14 of McElreath's Statistical Rethinking. In this example, there are divorce rate estimates $D_{EST,i}$ for different cities with measurements of standard error $D_{SD,i}$ as well. He specifies a model for predicting divorce rate from age at marriage $A$ and marriage rate $R$:
$$
D_{EST,i} \sim Normal(\mu_i, \sigma)
\\ \mu_i = \alpha + \beta_AA_i + \beta_RR_i
\\ D_{OBS,i} \sim Normal(D_{EST,i}, D_{SE,i})
\\ \alpha \sim Normal(0,10)
\\ \beta_A \sim Normal(0,10)
\\ \beta_R \sim Normal(0,10)
\\ \sigma \sim Cauchy(0,2.5)
$$
To add my part on, now imagine we previously fit a model on a different set of cities relating the divorce rate to the number of divorce lawyers $L$ in the city.  Something like this:
$$
\\ D_{OBS,i} \sim Normal(\mu_i, \sigma)
\\ \mu_i = \alpha + \beta_LL_i
\\ \alpha \sim Normal(0,10)
\\ \beta_L \sim Normal(0,10))
\\ \sigma \sim Cauchy(0,2.5)
$$
Now, in the first model, say we didn't actually measure the divorce rate at all, and only measured the number of divorce lawyers. We could sample the posterior from the first model to get a distribution of estimates for the divorce rate in the new set of cities.
Now, in the above model, in the third line, we don't necessarily have a normal distribution. Instead, we have a posterior distribution from the first model.
I understand that it is possible to approximate normal distributions from the predictions of the first model, but I have a few concerns. First, that information might be lost because if I use brms::posterior_predict, my understanding is that for each iteration the function takes a single parameter draw from the parameter posterior, and calculates predicted values for all new data. This should cause some covariation between divorce rate estimates, which would be lost just by summarizing the distribution mean and SD. Second, if the estimates don't fit well to a normal (or any other parametric distribution), then this seems like an issue.
So my question: is it valid to skip approximation of the predicted value and just use the posterior directly? Or is there a way to fit the two models together? And how can this be implemented in brms? Thanks!

Ok, I'm going to answer my own question now that I've done a bit more research:This Blog Post
Essentially the answer is to treat divorce rate as a missing value that we impute, and imputation comes from posterior_predict. So we make n datasets, each one with a different set of imputed values. Each dataset is fit to the same model then with brm_multiple
